# Internet Explorer fail compile external react component: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, external

I have a problem with React in Internet Explorer 11.

I am getting an error

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner}).**

Detail on:
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D&args[]=

when I use external react component.

Let me show a little code:

**node_modules/share-lib/src/components/ExternalComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';

   class ExternalComponent extends React.PureComponent {

     render() {
       return (
         <div>ExternalComponent</div>
       )
     }
   }

  export default ExternalComponent;
```

**Footer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ExternalComponent from 'share-lib/src/components/ExternalComponent';

class Footer extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
      return (
          <ExternalComponent />
      );
   }
}

export default Footer;
```

I use babel. Also tried babel-polyfill (desn't work, but I can did smth wrong, i don't know exactly)

How I can get rid of error:

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner}).** ?

Only in Internet Explorer and **only with external modules**

Here is my .babelrc

```
        {
       "presets": [
         [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
             "targets": {
                "node": "current"
              },
              "useBuiltIns": "usage"
          }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
      "plugins": [
        "es6-promise",
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
      ]
    }
```

Here are some versions of my packages:

```
"react": "16.2.0"
"react-dom": "16.2.0",
"babel-loader": "8.0.0-beta.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.37",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.37",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.37",
```

Comment: What version of react and react-dom are you using?

Comment: Added to question.

"react": "16.2.0"
"react-dom": "16.2.0",